# Java application, guitar tuner

Tags: java, api

I am currently trying to build a guitar tuner in JAVA using the netbeans IDE. I am hoping to capture the audio using "guitar rig" usb interface with an electric guitar as the input.
Does anyone have any guidance on which library would best suit this. javax.sound.sampled or javax.sound.midi?
I would also appreciate any guidance on how create the graphics and how best to capture the audio in java. What library is best suited to capture the input.
I am fairly new to programming but I am familiar with the best concepts of the JAVA language. Please forgive my naivety.

Regards to you all and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Make sure you get the right pitches. Several of the tuner apps for iPad are way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIDI is a representation for a musical score, not for sound. You could use it to play a note to tune against, but it doesn't do anything with incoming sound.

javax.sound.sampled comes closer, since it claims to include a function for capturing sound clips. But that's only the first step. To make a functioning tuner, you then have to determine what the fundamental frequency of the note is. Picking that out of the other noises and overtones may be a challenge. I'd be inclined to run a Fast Fourier Transform on the sample to obtain that information, but there may be a simpler cheat.